# Get access token via Paw

Tags: paw-app

Using the Paw app I would like to use the OAuth 2 "Get Access Token" functionality to automatically get or refresh token. I have no problem configuring it with the username and password and getting the proper response. However, the response is a JSON object, not just the access code, so Paw doesn't know what to do with it.

```
{"accessToken":"JWT content..."}
```

> Error OAuth 2 Response 'Access Token' No access token found in the
>   response.

Is it possible to tell Paw what property to read in the response in order to get/refresh the access token? Or does it need to be configured with two separate requests (not utilizing the handy built-in OAuth 2 dialogue)?

[image: OAuth 2 dialogue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return a JSON object then Paw expects it to be in the format

```
{"access_token": "....", ...}
```

which conforms to the OAuth2 standard https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4

I have been unable to find any information on how you could configure Paw to look for a different key.